# How to use the Fourier transform method to solve this inhomogeneous PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Question**: We define the full-range Fourier transform $F(k)$ of a function $f(x)$ and its inverse by
$$F(k)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \exp(ikx)f(x)dx, \text{   and  } f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\exp(-ikx)F(k)dk.$$
The function $u(x, t)$ obeys the PDE:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}+u=s(x)$$
where $s(x)$ is a known source term. At $t=0, u=f(x)$, with $f(x), s(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Use Fourier transforms to solve for $U(k, t)$.

**Attempt**: Let $U(k, t)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}u(x, t)e^{ikx}dx$.

Thus the PDE becomes:
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}+u-s(x))e^{ikx}dx=\frac{\partial U(k, t)}{\partial t}+k^4U(k, t)+U(k, t)-S(x, t)=0$$
Hence, we have
$$\frac{\partial U(k, t)}{\partial t}+(k^4+1)U(k, t)-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{ikx}s(x)dx=0$$

However, I'm not sure how to solve this problem further, as in the lecture, my teacher only talked about how to use Fourier transfer method solve homogeneous PDEs. This is an optional question in my homework. Can someone tell me how to solve this type of questions?

Thank you for your attention, I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the particular form of $f(x)$ an $s(x)$, the best you can do here is to express the solution as the inverse Fourier transform of some expression consisting of known quantities [in fact, even if you knew $f(x)$ and $s(x)$, this is likely the best you could do since the final integration would be very difficult].

Say $S(k)$ is the transform of $s(x)$. Then you have $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}(k,t) + (k^4 + 1)U(k,t) = S(k).$$ Formally, treating $k$ like a constant, this is an ODE in time. It can be solved using an integrating factor: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big( U(k,t) e^{(k^4+1)t} \big) = e^{(k^4+1)t} S(k).$$ Integrating from $0$ up to some $t$ (and letting $F(k)$ be the transform of $f(x)$), we see $$U(k,t)e^{(k^4+1)t} - F(k)= S(k)\int^t_{0} e^{(k^4+1)\tau}d\tau = \frac{S(k)}{k^4+1}(e^{(k^4+1)t} - 1)$$ so $$U(k,t) = F(k)e^{-(k^4+1)t}  + \frac{S(k)}{k^4+1}(1 - e^{-(k^4+1)t}).$$ Thus $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left(F(k) e^{-(k^4+1)t - ixk} + \frac{S(k)}{k^4+1} (1-e^{-(k^4+1)t})e^{-ixk} \right) dk$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining in details. This is very well explained, I completely understand now!

Comment: I just realised you didn't use the IC and BCs anywhere. I was just wondering don't we need to use them since they are given?

Comment: The IC is used when integrating because $U(k,0) = F(k)$. There is bo boundary condition on $u$; the boundary conditions on $s,f$ are probably just there to ensure the FTs are well-defined.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!